# Is there any implementation of degree distribution in JUNG2 API?

Tags: java, graph-theory, jung, jung2

I tried to look in the documentation of the verision 2, but I didnt find anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not, but it's pretty trivial to loop over the vertices in a graph and build up a representation of the degree distribution, e.g.:

```
int[] degreeCounts = new int[graph.getVertexCount()];
for (V v : graph.getVertices()) {
  degreeCounts[graph.getDegree(v)]++;
}
```

Substitute the appropriate degree function (indegree, outdegree) as needed.